# Is Appium server single thread?

Tags: appium, autotest, appium-java

I want ...
Using Server(including appium server), making many clients do auto testing.
I got a one question.

If many clients do auto test through server(in aws, has appium server), Can appium server do multithreading? (I already knew about tomcat can multithreading due to it's thread pool)

or It is possible that make many appium server(when a client start auto test) and do auto test through each and then stop it(when the auto test is done) so that many clients can do auto test at the same time?

In conclusion,
I want to make a server that can do auto test for many clients at the same time and that server has appium server(clients do not know about appium server). All things about auto test setting is in Server(in aws, used by clients). All clients don't know at all about auto test setting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Appium it's a single server, but you can create Appium Grid and use multiple serves to run tests
Appium Grid [example](https://www.browserstack.com/guide/set-up-appium-grid)
Selenium Grid [here](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/grid/)

Comment: Thank you so much for your good answer. It was a great help to me!! :)

Comment: Can I ask you a few more questions?
I saw some opinions that open several sessions with one appium server using different ports, but some say no, so do you know about it?